# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

Tags: java, mysql, connectivity

I used the following code for retrieving a table 'at' in database 'scribe' made in mysql to be displayed in a JTable 'shdtbl' but it is showing this exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
```

The code:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)shdtbl.getModel();
int i=1,j=1;
Vector<String> v=new Vector();
try {
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(f.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
try {
    ResultSet rs0=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/scribe","root","shivam").createStatement().executeQuery("select * from at;");
    while(i<=4){
        if(rs0.next()){
             rs0.absolute(j);
             v.addElement(rs0.getString(i));
             if(i==4){
                 j++;
                 dtm.addRow(v);
                 v.clear();
                 i=0;
             }
         }
         i++;
     }
} 
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(f.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Plz help.

Comment: Could you indicate on which line the exception is occurring?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In future please format your code readably.  I took care of it for you this time.

Comment: @Alan, it is not showing line number.

Answer (score 1):

Check that jTable index starts from zero.